# Vagrant corrupted index file C:\Users\USERNAME\.vagrant.d/data/machine-index/index

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant, windows-8.1

My Windows 8.1 just crashed. Now I have some files on my dist that are corrupted. This includes my vagrant machine index (Not shure if the naming is right but I know that it is this file -> C:\Users\USERNAME.vagrant.d/data/machine-index/index).

So There is a lot of binary or hexdecimal stuff in there (Again not shure because I don't deal with this stuff usualy so correct me if I'm wrong!) And Vagrant spits out the following message if I try to start everything after boot.

`vagrant up` returns this

```
The machine index which stores all required information about
running Vagrant environments has become corrupt. This is usually
caused by external tampering of the Vagrant data folder.

Vagrant cannot manage any Vagrant environments if the index is
corrupt. Please attempt to manually correct it. If you are unable
to manually correct it, then remove the data file at the path below.
This will leave all existing Vagrant environments "orphaned" and
they'll have to be destroyed manually.

Path: C:/Users/Username/.vagrant.d/data/machine-index/index
```

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Same thing happened to me. So I just deleted the index file and the .lock file from the machine-index folder to get Vagrant working again.

Comment: That worked for me too. Just don't forget to delete BOTH files (if present) index.lock and index. I firstly deleted only .lock and it did not worked :)

Comment: It wasn't clear for me and I think it worth mention: this fix not only put Vagrant to work again but also allows Vagrant to find your VMs again when running commands like `vagrant up vm-name` etc. (as long as you have the Vagrantfile in place and all the .vagrant files untouched).

Comment: This saved my day. I bought a new mac, and used superduper and rsync finished the system restore. Everything works fine but I can not boot my vagrant. The error message was, the machine I'm trying to boot is locked. I spent two hours to figure out how to resolve this until reaching here. So just delete index, index.lock from ~/.vagrant.d, and go the vagrant directory to do vagrant up will finish the job.

Comment: best! solution..!

Comment: Vagrant is up now but I can access the URL in browser, showing **devsites.com refused to connect.** error

Comment: Error message is so scary yet the solution is so simple. Thanks

Comment: `This will leave all existing Vagrant environments "orphaned" and
they'll have to be destroyed manually.` But I don't want to destroy my vagrant box. Presumably following this answer will solve everything without having to "destroy the vagrant environment manually"?

Comment: ^ Well I followed the answer's directions and everything appears to be working as intended so i'd assume the above warning message was a non-issue.

Comment: For those of you seeing this answer and immediately wondering where the files are to delete (like I did).

They are in the path specified at the end of the error message.

Answer (score 3):

When using Vagrant 2.2.5 in Windows 10, I had to navigate to `/Users/{yourname}/.vagrant.d/data/machine-index` and remove both `index` and `index.lock`, so `rm index` then `rm index.lock`.

Finally I navigated back to Homestead folder and ran `vagrant up`.

Comment: PS: yes, and I should update my vagrant - I will do it after this project, I promise! (:

Answer (score 0):

When accidentally my laptop crashed, I had the same vagrant issue (index) on my first attempt to run vagrant up.

```
The machine index which stores all required information about
running Vagrant environments has become corrupt. This is usually
caused by external tampering of the Vagrant data folder.

Vagrant cannot manage any Vagrant environments if the index is
corrupt. Please attempt to manually correct it. If you are unable
to manually correct it, then remove the data file at the path below.
This will leave all existing Vagrant environments "orphaned" and
they'll have to be destroyed manually.

Path: C:/Users/{user}/.vagrant.d/data/machine-index/index
```

Unfortunately my issue was not solved by deleting the index and index.lock files as the most voted up answer told. I rebooted my vm using virtualbox GUI (used as VM provider) and shown up the following message.

```
Entering emergency mode. Exit the shell to continue.
Type "journalctl" to view system logs.
You might want to save "/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt" to a USB stick or /boot
after mounting them and attach it to a bug report.
```

I realised that crash produced errors on VM's FS. So after searching and investigation I overcame that issue by executing the command below.

```
xfs_repair -v -L /dev/dm-0
```

Environment info: OS windows10, virtual-box 6.1, vagrant 2.2.7 and vm-os centos7